# Spaces In Text Document Name Through Batch User Input

Tags: batch-file, text, input, user-input

I am trying to make an "AI". It functions by making a file and naming it after the user input, then asking what say when the input is put in again. But, when you add a space, It names it just after the first word, and doesn't allow it to be called up next time!

Here Is the part that learns from user input:

```
:learn
cls
echo I don't know anything about "%cat%". Can you tell me what you know.
echo.
set /p catinfo=Tell me what you know:
echo %catinfo% >> brain\%cat%.txt
set txt=That's cool, now I know.
(
echo %name%
) > vf2.txt
set txt=Cool now I know about %cat%.
cls
goto startup
```

And this is what reads the text document:

```
:learned
(
set /p catinfo=
) < brain\%cat%.txt
set txt=%catinfo%
color e
echo %catinfo%
%speech% "%catinfo%"
color a
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000>nul
cls
goto startup
```

I just wanted the user to be able to use spaces to talk to the computer. Sorry about this probably pretty simple question, but I would like it to be more streamline than using underscores.

Thanks!

-Simon

Comment: Any time there is a space in a file path you need to surround the whole path with "quotes".  It is a best practice to use them regardless of them being needed or not.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks for the quick response! So, I put quotes around the "if exist" part. When I decided to test it, it just flashed unexpected error, then crashed. Is there something I did wrong?

Comment: I do not see any `IF EXIST` in your code.  If you changed your code then update your question. I am not omniscient.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it! Thanks SOOOO much for the answer, I knew about it for the set responses, I never though about doing it for this part. Thanks! Sorry for the other part, I wasn't thinking...